# Cloud code causes "Tried to save an object with a pointer to a new, unsaved object" when saving pointers

Tags: parse-platform

In my app, I have users and posts, and I am trying to instantiate my Activity class which has pointers to user and post objects. Here is my code:

```
var Activity = Parse.Object.extend("Activity");
var User = Parse.Object.extend("_User");
var Post = Parse.Object.extend("Posts");

var activityHandler = function(request, response){
    //toUser is the objectId of the User not the object itself.
    var toUserId = request.toUser;
    var fromUserId = request.fromUser;
    var postId = request.post;
    var arg = request.argument;


    var toUser = new User();
    toUser.set("objectId",toUserId);
    var fromUser = new User();
    fromUser.set("objectId",fromUserId);
    var post = new Post();
    post.set("objectId",postId);

    var activity = new Activity();
    activity.set("activityFrom", fromUser);
    activity.set("activityTo", toUser);
    activity.set("argument", arg);
    activity.set("post", post);
    activity.save(null, {
        useMasterKey: true,

            success: function(o){
        console.log("activity logged successfully");
        response.success();
            },
            error: function(err){
        console.log(err);
            },
        }
    );
};

Parse.Cloud.define("createActivity", activityHandler);
```

The code is self-explanatory, but just to summarize, the client sends the appropriate user and post IDs, and the cloud function should instantiate a new `Activity` object, with pointers to the users and post. However, when I try to save, I'm getting:

`{"code":141,"error":"Uncaught Tried to save an object with a pointer to a new, unsaved object."}`

The problem is that, the object IDs sent to the function are completely valid, already-existing objects in the database. ACL is also not an issue as I'm on the master key.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was my bad.

There were multiple problems with my code.

1. I was using `object.set("objectId", id);` syntax, which actually should be `object.id = id`. I'm not sure if it is necessary, maybe it would work without that change too, but I've read everywhere that it's a bad practice.
2. I wasn't getting the request parameters correctly. I was using `request.param1` instead of `request.params.param1`, and the parameter variable was undefined. I haven't checked if it was undefined or not for a long time, as the error message wasn't really helpful about parameter being undefined, from my perspective back then. (now it makes sense, no ID, and it automatically tries to create a new object)

I've corrected them and it does save correctly now.

Comment: i'm kind of facing the same problem here, could explain the  object.id=id to me pls?, does that mean we should use object.set("object", object.id) instead? cheers

Comment: you should use `.id` only for id, createdAt and updatedAt. for all the others (AFAIK), use `.set('property', val);` @libra

Answer (score 0):

This also happens when you forget to call the method:

```
response.success(object);
```