# How do I create a Parse.com object and a pointer object in the same loop

Tags: javascript, pointers, parse-platform

I'm using the Parse.com javascript SDK and I'm trying to figure out how to create an object with a pointer to multiple another object that do not yet exist. For instance lets say I have three classes Car, Wheel, Bumper. The car object contains a pointer to a the wheel and the bumper. I'm looping through an array to create the car, and I want to also create a bumper object and a wheel object but I'm confused as to the best way to do this.

```
var Car = Parse.Object.extend("Car");
var car = new Car();

car.set("name", "the name");
car.set("color", "the color");

car.save(null, {
  success: function(album) {
    // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
    alert('New object created with objectId: ' + car.id);
  },
  error: function(car, error) {
    // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
    alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
  }
});
```

Do I create the car object first? and then create each of the other wto objects and save them as pointers later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two other objects must first exist (be saved to Parse) before you are able to add pointers to them in your Car object.

If the Wheel and Bumper objects do not exist yet, you could have something along the lines of:

```
// Create new Wheel -> assign attributes -> save object
// Create new Bumper -> assign attributes -> save object
car.add("wheel", wheelObject);
car.add("bumper", bumperObject);
car.save(null, { ...
```

[As mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250057/cloud-code-causes-tried-to-save-an-object-with-a-pointer-to-a-new-unsaved-obje) if you try to perform a save with a pointer to an unsaved object, you will get the following error

```
{"code":141,"error":"Uncaught Tried to save an object with a pointer to a new, unsaved object."}
```

Comment: are those functions synchronous ? do you have to wait till the object is saved to reference it?

Comment: Yes you will have to wait until those objects have been saved to add the pointer references. `object.add` only requires that you are able to reference another Parse object so it is neither synchronous nor asynchronous.